# How to join two tables while returning a single row from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Here's my sample table:

```
Model Table

MODEL_NO    | MODEL_NAME| ITEM_CODE 
  A1            TEST        1
  A1            TEST        2 
  A2            TEST2       1
  A2            TEST2       2


Data Table

DATE           MODEL_NO    DATA_VAL
2014-11-10        A1         3.4
2014-11-10        A1         4.2
2014-11-11        A2         1.9
2014-11-12        A2         1.8
```

Desired Result:

```
   DATE        MODEL_NO    DATA_VAL   MODEL_NAME
2014-11-10        A1         3.4        TEST
2014-11-10        A1         4.2        TEST
2014-11-11        A2         1.9        TEST2
2014-11-12        A2         1.8        TEST2
```

I thought about using Subquery or do a simple table join with distinct, but I'd like to know if there's a preferred way of doing this.

Here's an example of using distinct

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATA_TB.DATE, DATA_TB.MODEL_NO, DATA_TB.DATA_VAL, MODEL_TB.MODEL_NAME
FROM DATA_TB
LEFT JOIN MODEL_TB
  ON DATA_TB.MODEL_NO = MODEL_TB.MODEL_NO
```

The production query related to the above question is actually much more longer and it's selecting about 25 columns, but I've simplified the question down to what I'm trying to achieve.

Is distinct the best way to achieve this? Or utilize group by? or subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First select the `distinct Model_no and model_name` from `model table` then `join` the result with `data table`.   Try this.

```
SELECT a.DATE ,a.MODEL_NO,a.DATA_VAL,B.MODEL_NAME
FROM   data a
       JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT MODEL_NO,
                             MODEL_NAME
             FROM   model) B
         ON a.MODEL_NO = b.MODEL_NO
```